# Is it feasible to sign Deb package using a cert issued by Trusted CA or signing with a GPG Key Pair Signed by a Trusted CA

Tags: apt, deb, gnupg, certificates

I am trying to sign our custom deb install packages so that the end users can verify the signature before installing it. 
Using GPG Key pair generated locally and used for signing, requires the end user to download/import it on the target machine to verify the package signature.

On Windows, a vendor can sign the binaries with a key signed by a trusted root CA like DigiCert and on the target machine end user does not need to install the public key/cert from that vendor. And the signature verification checks the trusted root chain with the installed Root CA certificates. 
Is this feasible/supported organically in Linux?

Is one of the following feasible to achieve I described above:
1> Generate a GPG Key Pair signed by a Trusted Root CA
2> Signing a GPG Key Pair ganerated by a Trusted Root CA (like DigiCert)
3> Signing rpm/deb packages and with a Cert issued by a Trusted Root CA

thank you,
Kumar Talinki

Comment: packages can only be signed with PGP keypairs.  Unless you mean some other type of digital signature?

Comment: @ThomasWard thank you! Trying to sign deb package with a key whose trust chains to a trusted root CA cert that is installed by default on the target Ubuntu machines. Trying to see if there is a way we can get away from sharing/publishing the my GPG public key. And use the trusted root CA certs that get installed on the target machine by default.
Is there another digital signature mechanism in Linux other than GPG ?